# Problem with Starteam and Cruise Control.Net

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, starteam

Does anyone have problem getting files from starteam using the cruise control tool for setting up automatic build job??

The script seems to run fine but fail after some time with the error message 
Error occurred:
Unable to read data from the network: the connection to the StarTeam server has been lost.

I am not sure whether the problem is the way our Starteam server has been setup, we have 4 licenses shared across the team and the server automatically logs people out if it detects inactivity for a period of time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got StarTeam working with cruise control.net so I can tell you that it works, but its a pain, especially the fact that starteam won't remove deleted files from working directories on its own.
I've seen that error once before, but If I remember right, it had to do with an IPSec configuration problem and was immediate, not after a delay. Is the amount of time it takes to fail shorter/longer/same as the timeout for inactivity? Are any/all/none of your source files making it into the working directory before it fails?